# Return some data based on a known id in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am making a CRUD application in jquery and i have this problem in my application.To edit a record i am getting the id of the record successfully.

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>"  class="update_btn">Edit</a>
```

I want to retrieve the id and that works.

```
$('.update_btn').live("click",function() 
{
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = 'msg_id='+ ID;
//alert(dataString);

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
 url: "get-data.php",
 dataType: 'json',
 cache: false,
 success: function(data){
 //getData()
 }
});
return false;
});
```

However,how can i use the retrieved id to

```
//get-data.php
include('db.php');
if($_POST['msg_id'])
{
$id=$_POST['msg_id'];
$id = mysql_escape_String($id);
$sql_in= mysql_query("SELECT msg FROM messages where msg_id='$id'");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($sql_in);
$msg=$r['msg'];
echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

return the data from the select query.Is this possible?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `data` option in your ajax request to send your id first:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get-data.php",
   dataType: 'json',
   data: dataString , // <--------- added this line
   cache: false,
   success: function(data){
     //getData()
 }
});
```

Now you will be able to get it in PHP with what you are doing eg `$_POST['msg_id']`

Comment: Worth noting that you can use an object `{msg_id: ID}` instead of a formatted string.

Comment: I never thought you were allowed to do that in php!.Thanks Blaster and jadkik94.